# Function is not recognized in React SSR using puppeteer headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use a React custom component called `Grid` inside a function called `matrix`, Once `matrix` get executed it should mount `Grid` into `ReactDOMServer`. But `window` doesn't recognize it and throws an error instead..

I have a script tag in puppeteer headless browser that injects this function into the DOM, and a div element `matrix${index}` that should serve as the place were to inject `Grid` into.

puppeteer configuration file: (code emitted for clarity)

```
module.exports = async (template, reportData) => {

    ...

    await page.addScriptTag({ path: './src/metrics/matrix.js' });`

    ...
```

As well as the function `matrix` to be executed:

```
const React = require('react');
const Grid= React.createFactory(require('../components/Grid'));

----------v // matrix is dimmed in my editor
function matrix(data) {
    const tableConfig = data.resp_example.meta.map((value, i) => ({
        title: (value.name || value.type).toUpperCase(),
        value: value => value[i]
    }));
    const values = data[0] && data[0].values[0];
    const matrix = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <Grid config={tableConfig} data={values.samples[0].y} />
    );
    const matrixId = document.getElementById(`matrix${index}`);
    document.getElementById(`matrix${index}`).style.height = '400px';
    matrixId.innerHTML = matrix;
}

module.exports = matrix;
```

The line that executes this function looks like so:

```
window.matrix(data);
```

That line yields the following error:

```
(node:6924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: window.matrix is not a function
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:346
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:70
    at Object.e.w (https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js:1:94464)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:14
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:121:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:110:27)   
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:48:31)
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:23)   
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.evaluate (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:782:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\ReportService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:23)
    at e (C:\workspace\ReportService\build\server.js:1:6160)
    at e.next (<anonymous>)
    at a (C:\workspace\ReportService\build\server.js:1:4946)
    at s (C:\workspace\ReportService\build\server.js:1:6831)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6924) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It looks like everything should be OK and the function should render `Grid` into the DOM, Does anyone knows what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: './src/metrics/matrix.js' do you have that in the server running the page?

Comment: @hardkoded - affirmative

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error stems from a wrong usage of `Grid` as a ES6 classes component syntax within node, Since `Grid` created by `createReactClass`, i.e:

`const Grid = React.createReactClass({ ... });`

The options to resolve that are:

1. configure webpack babel transpiler to interpret ES6 classes:

````
   npm install --save-dev babel-loader@6.2.1
   npm install --save-dev babel-core@6.4.5
   npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13
   npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react@6.3.13```
````

2. Use: `const matrix = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
       Grid({ config: {tableConfig}, data: {values.samples[0].y} })
   );`

   Instead of:
       `const matrix = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
       <Grid config={tableConfig} data={values.samples[0].y} />
   );`

More information can be found @ [React Without ES6](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html)